# How can I create pure Java Android app projects only?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, intellij-idea

Since very recently, all new Android App projects with Android Studio and IntelliJ have been Java and I want to keep it that way. Recently however they introduce me forcibly to Kotlin, which I don't know and don't want to learn. Do I have to downgrade and block upgrades to get this functionality back to what it was, or what do I have to change to get my Java templates and old default behaviour back to what it was, say in 2022/beginning 2023?

I create a new project as always and now get *.kt files instead of *.java, and all the activity templates have become Kotlin. I have browsed all settings and can't work out where or how to change them to fall back or add the feature I want. I also can't see plugins which eventually could add the old mech.

Comment: "Recently however they introduce me forcibly to Kotlin" -- they default to Kotlin. You can use Java in any Android Studio project. "what do I have to change to get my Java templates" -- I doubt those are coming back in terms of official support. IMHO, those templates were never very good. While *you* may not want to deal with Kotlin, please bear in mind that most of the ecosystem is moving to Kotlin, just as most of iOS development has moved to Swift and away from Objective-C. You will be increasingly isolated as a pure-Java developer, but that is certainly your choice to make.

Comment: Ok, this is what I feared and suspected. Now I have installed the Jetbrains Toolbox which allows me to install and keep different versions of the IDE side by side and installed the version 2023.1.5 and downgraded the project gradle from 8.0.0 to 7.4.0, which allows me to develop old fashioned. For the moment I keep both versions. ... now I have to work out how to accept here your answer :-)

Comment: You don't need an older IDE to continue to use Java, nor do you need an older version of AGP - they all work just fine with fully Java based projects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Recently however they introduce me forcibly to Kotlin

It's more that they default projects to incorporating Kotlin into the build scripts and that templates are only available for Kotlin. You can still use Java, and there's nothing that you need to add to the project to use Java.

> what do I have to change to get my Java templates

I doubt those are coming back in terms of official support. IMHO, those templates were never very good, often demonstrating anti-patterns or using obsolete techniques. Cutting back to just Kotlin templates might help them do a better job of maintaining the smaller roster.

There might be a plugin that offers Java templates. I am not aware of any, but I have never looked for any either.

> which I don't know and don't want to learn

You do not have to learn Kotlin. However, please understand that you will be increasingly isolated. The Android ecosystem is moving *strongly* towards Kotlin, just as the iOS ecosystem moved towards Swift. Right now, trying to learn Objective-C-based iOS development is very difficult, because documentation and tooling is Swift-centric. The same thing will be true for Android app development in another couple of years.

Also, note that certain technologies, such as Jetpack Compose, require Kotlin.

FWIW, if you would like to at least be somewhat conversant in Kotlin, for reading documentation and blog posts and stuff, [here is a free book of mine on the subject](https://commonsware.com/Kotlin), though it is getting a bit old.

Comment: I am aware of being isolated, but I am now past 60 years old and simply can't follow a new programming language in a way to become a professional. I just see in Kotlin an attempt to make it a multi-platform language, which certainly has its perks, but none of which I can make use of. I see from the syntax, that Kotlin is Swift oriented and that made me, honestly, sick. The unexplainable question marks and stuff like that drive me insane :-)

I'll have a look into your book, though.